# Term for describing auditory memory similar to 'eidetic' (for visual memory)

Tags: meaning, phrases, music, scientific-language

Is there a similar term for eidetic memory, but for sound?

> An [eidetic memory](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eidetic) is the ability to remember things in exact detail, *as if you can see* them in your mind:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eidetic)

The measure of eidetic memory is calculated in seconds, and minutes. It is usually stronger in children and almost unknown in adults.

For this task, I would think: "as if you can ***hear*** them in your mind" describes it fairly  well.

All dictionary sources define the term by "seeing"...but is it the same for hearing, smell, and  even touch ?

I suppose it would be better developed in musicians as opposed to those of us who are less talented; it seems to be particularly  well-developed in savants who can replicate perfectly a tune after hearing it once only.

Does "eidetic memory" apply here also?

Comment: As a  musician who has a poor memory, I can vouch that the ability to remember a series of notes varies widely in the musical community. Many musicians can remember a tune *visually,* especially if they have perfect pitch. As they hear it, they can imagine both the keys on a piano and the notes on the stave.  I spoke about this to a pianist with a reputation for memorising really fast. He told me he memorised (a) the sound (b) the finger movements (muscle memory) (c) the appearance on the staff.  I suspect that all of these were helped by the fact he just had a good memory in general.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica That is extremely insightful...perhaps an answer?

Comment: I could answer but it would require  fair amount of online research on my part. My recommendation is that you delete the question here and ask it here instead https://psychology.stackexchange.com/  You may even find that it has been answered in some form already. P.S. touch memory is "haptic" and sound memory is "echoic"   Some definitions of eidetic allow it to be used for senses other than vision.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Your suggestion that some musicians "see" notes on a page and "feel" them  is interesting. Thank you...I will take that under consideration and possibly re-post tomorrow.  The issue is that the deletion of a question with an answer  is problematic. I hesitate to post on another SE site as most are very unwelcoming to new users. That includes us.

Comment: That's a sad commentary. I have developed a thick skin from contributing to Stack Exchange. Its denizens vary from extreme pedants to open-minded souls.   Best to read some existing questions and answers there to get the general tenor. Also read up a little beforehand about  *eidetic, haptic, echoic *, etc. This way you can be very specific about your question and you may even find the answers online anyway. Try Googling the terms and see what you can find. If you are still not sure, you can evidence that you have done some research for yourself .

Comment: Maybe it’s called  ***phonographic memory***  ;-)

Comment: This has [a good answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/20980/27529) on Psychology SE. "Eidetic memory" is claimed to encompass the audio aspect there.

Comment: Not sure if my answer helps, you appear to ask for a specific term for auditory memory but also if eidetic memory covers visual as well ass auditory memory. So what you actually looking for?

Comment: Sorry @user66974, but I now think this question is a dupe on another site. I up-voted your answer, but I will not check it off because I think we need to close this question, and checking off an answer makes it more difficult to delete. That said, your answer was indeed the answer.

Comment: If a similar question was posted on another site it doesn’t mean that this is a dupe, as long as it is on topic from a linguistic point of view.

Comment: @user66974 I had a long thought out now-deleted answer to this comment...lemme think on it.

Comment: The term [*Audiation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audiation) covers musical memory, though it also includes being able to mentally "hear" music that you have not previously heard aloud (the musical equivalent of visualising) so I'm not sure if that makes it too broad a term for you.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica That was an astute comment...so maybe improving memory in general can improve musical skill?

Answer (score 1):

***[Echoic memory](https://www.healthline.com/health/echoic-memory)*** , or auditory sensory memory

> is a type of memory that stores audio information (sound). ...

> The purpose of echoic memory is to store audio information as the brain processes the sound. It also holds bits of audio information, which gives meaning to the overall sound.

(healthline.com)

Collins Dictionary defines [echoic memory](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/echoic-memory) as:

(psychology)

> the ability to recapture the exact impression of a sound shortly after the sound has finished

Comment: But [an] 'eidetic memory' goes beyond 'visual memory'; it is the ability to remember things as if you can see them in your mind and _in exact detail_.

Answer (score 0):

How about "aural"?  "...of or relating to the ear or to the sense of hearing." (from Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Could you provide a link? It would also help if you explained why you think your term is appropriate.